# Disable Line Wrapping in a multi-line UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, string, uilabel, word-wrap

Is there a way with a multi-line label (myLabel.numberOfLines = 0) to disable any kind of line wrapping so that if a line is too long to fit on one line of the label it just stops/kind of breaks off and doesnt wrap to the line below? So I can use "\n" to assign strings to other lines of the label. I know lines that are too long automatically wrap to the next line but I dont know if there is a no line wrap option.

So If I had a label with a line max of 10 chars per line

```
var firstLine : String = "This is 16 chars"
var secondLine : String = "This is too long"
myLabel.text = firstLine + secondLine
// It would look like this:
```

Output:

```
This is 16
This is to
```

As shown it just cuts off and doesnt wrap each line even though they dont fit

Comment: Cant understand the question...if you want a 1 line label just set `numberOfLines = 1`, you set it = 0 and you want it to be 1 line????

Comment: I made it more clear in the example at the bottom. Multiple lines

Comment: Have you tried setting lineBreakMode of `ByClipping`? I haven't used it where numberOfLines is also 0, but worth a try.

Comment: ByClipping does not seem to work. A line still wraps to the next when its too long.

Answer (score 1):

`firstLine + secondLine` will become 1 string `This is 16 charsThis is too long`, i dont think you can do something like described without code, you have to manually cut off the strings to 10 characters and add \n at the end, so it will become `This is 16\nThis is to`

Something like :

```
var string = message
let fontAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
var size = (string as NSString).sizeWithAttributes(fontAttributes)

while size.width > label.width {
        string.removeAtIndex(string.endIndex.predecessor())
        size = (string as NSString).sizeWithAttributes(fontAttributes)
}
string = string+"\n"
```

Comment: The problem is idk the length of a line neccasarily so I wanted it to automatically have it cut off.

Comment: I have an idea that you can count the size of the string then strip off 1 by 1 character until it's fit the label's width, not sure if its the best idea since its pretty much loop

Comment: check the answer and try it, i think got a better way to solve this but this is the only way i have now

Comment: I mean it works if I know how many chars can fit on a line but if the length of the label changes, idk how many can fit on it, unless there is a way to dynamically calculate that when it changes

Comment: You can use this to calculate again if the length change also

Answer (score 0):

If you have desired length of your label, you can try this stupid but work method: To cut the string by yourself, use stringByPaddingToLength method.

Try below codes:

```
self.tempLabel.text = @"This is 16 chars fbaebfbefbefbeif";
self.tempLabel.text = [self.tempLabel.text stringByPaddingToLength:10 withString:@"" startingAtIndex:0];
```

See magic happens

Comment: The problem is idk how many characters can fit in a line (10 was just for the example)

Comment: you can try to find the length of each char needs first:

CGSize textSize = [[label text] sizeWithFont:[label font]];
CGFloat strikeWidth = textSize.width;
NSUInteger characterCount = [myString length];
CGFloat eachCharLength = strikeWidth/characterCount;

then use the label width to calculate how many words it can fit a line:
CGFloat f = self.tempLabel.frame.size.width/eachCharLength;
NSInteger numberOfCharCapicityInLine  = floorf(f);

Then,

self.tempLabel.text = [self.tempLabel.text stringByPaddingToLength: numberOfCharCapicityInLine withString:@"" startingAtIndex:0];

Comment: The syntax may not right but the logic you can follow cuz I'm not using my MAC.